# Ansible save registered variable to a file using lineinfile module

Tags: automation, ansible, devops, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to save the value of a registered variable to a file using lineinfile module, I have 3 hosts in hosts file, but the output contain only 2 host information. Am I missing anything in the lineinfile module?

count.yaml

```
---
- name: Ansbile script to save command line output
  hosts: all
  become_user: root
  tasks:

  - name: create a file
    file:
     path: /home/codemaster/count.txt
     state: touch
     force: yes
    delegate_to: localhost


  - name: Check End Points 
    shell: kamctl online | wc -l
    register: ep

  - name: save result to a file
    lineinfile:
      dest: /home/codemaster/count.txt
      line: "{{ inventory_hostname + ' ' + ep.stdout }}"
      insertafter: EOF
    delegate_to: localhost
```

hosts_file

```
[webrtc]
128.6.6.10 
128.6.6.12 
128.6.6.18
```

OUTPUT:

```
[codemaster@127.9.7.6 ~]$ cat count.txt
128.6.6.10 4694
128.6.6.12 4280
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid concurrent writing from all hosts. Write it in one task. For example,

```yaml
 - name: save result to a file
   lineinfile:
     dest: /home/codemaster/count.txt
     line: "{{ item }} {{ hostvars[item].ep.stdout }}"
     insertafter: EOF
   loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
   delegate_to: localhost
   run_once: true
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>